# get results on javascript from a php

Tags: javascript, php, html

first of all good Morning.
I am working on a search form and it calls a php that connects to a mysql database to get the results.

My problem is i am trying to get the results from my php...
When i search and calls the function on php it shows on another page...
Is there a way of know how to get the data from the php to javascript?

My html search form:

```
<div class="quicky-search pesquisaa-form">
                            <form id="pesquisaa" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                             <fieldset>
                                <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Pesquisar"/>
                                <button type="submit" value="Search" class="submity-search"><span class="icon-search"></span></button>
                             </fieldset>
                            </form>
                         </div>
```

My script inside the html:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#pesquisaa').validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
    url: 'assets/email/pesquisar-cdd.php',
    success: function() {
    $('#pesquisaa').hide();
    $('#pesquisaa-form').append(PS: I NEED THE RESULT INSIDE HERE TO SHOW ON MY HTML PAGE)
    }
    });
    }
});         
});
</script>
```

Now my PHP:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    /*
        localhost - it's location of the mysql server, usually localhost
        root - your username
        third is your password

        if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
    */

    mysql_select_db("atuacdd") or die(mysql_error());
    /* tutorial_search is the name of database we've created */
?>
<?php
    $query = $_POST['query']; 
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 3;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cidades
            WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`text` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
        // articles is the name of our table

        // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
        // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
        // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<p><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['text']."</p>";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "Desculpe não atuamos nesta Cidade desejada!";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Tamanho Minimo é ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Doorknob what did you meant by the "AJAX"???

Answer (score 0):

use

```
success: function(data){

}
```

instead of

```
success: function(){

}
```

you will get the data echoed on php side.

Comment: Could you please get the code above and make it for me? i got confused sorry

Comment: Its still not working how about the:
$('#pesquisaa').hide();
    $('#pesquisaa-form').append("<p class='alert alert-success'>Obrigado, Recebemos seu Email com Sucesso.</p>")

Comment: success: function(data){
$('#pesquisaa').hide();
$('#pesquisaa-form').append(data);
});

Comment: for some how its not showing up the results and the "$('#pesquisaa').hide();" this function its to hide the search form after then show the results

Comment: how i will send the all the code?
I have the HTML form on the first post i made above

Comment: I can't answer my ownt question how will i send you the hole html page?

Comment: I mean just the ids the way they are encapsulated
is pesquisaa inside pesquisaa-form or is it otherwise??

Comment: its is inside the javascript its just the id from the java script

Comment: No not that i mean the div element, is  pesquisaa inside pesquisaa-form??

Comment: Yes everything is inside there but its not showing up the results, can you please read all the codes above you will see there

Comment: Oh my bad, so add this
<script>
$(function(){
$('#pesquisaa').validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
    url: 'assets/email/pesquisar-cdd.php',
    success: function(data) {
    $('#pesquisaa').hide();
    $('#pesquisaa-form').append(data);
    }
    });
    }
});         
});
</script>
Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Sorry nothing yet its not showing the damn result i don't know why can you look up on my html up there and see if i setted the corrects ids on the classes please

Comment: <script>
$(function(){
$('#pesquisaa').validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
    url: 'assets/email/pesquisar-cdd.php',
    success: function(data) {
    $('#pesquisaa').hide();
    $('#pesquisaa-form').append(data)
    }
    });
    }
});         
});
</script>

Comment: <script>
$(function(){
$('#pesquisaa').validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({url: 'assets/email/pesquisar-cdd.php',    success: function(data) {$('#pesquisaa').hide();
    console.log(data);
    $('#pesquisaa-form').append(data);}});}
});});
</script>'
Please put the code as it is.
So I want you to tell following:
1>Check out the console of browser and check if the data from the backend is proper.2>Is'nt the hide functionality working?3>Open up he network tab in the console and check the http request which communicates with the php script, Is it returning the data?

Comment: I followed everything you told me nothing yet =( not working idk why idk whats wrong

Comment: i fixed it now on the pesquisar-cdd.php its doing a loop when  search the query it keeps showing the others searchs that i looked up for!!!